# Resizing n pictures to fit into certain height and width - right location / class to define property?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am pretty new to CSS / HTML and I hope this question is not too stupid

I wanted to take an amount of pictures, that should all fit the full width. After a long trial and error, I figured that by adding a min-width of 33.33% and max-width of 33.33% within the individual IDs, I got a result that I am happy with. With all the other ones, the images were very huge or too narrow and not scaled properly. The height was always correct though.

However I am sure that this probably goes easier than this?

I tried

1. adding min-width: / max-width 33.33% to the .container class.
2. flex-basis: 33.33%
3. min-width and width: 33.33% in .image-category

Why does only adding the property to the ID helped out? Am I doing something wrong or is it a convention?

```css
.container{
display: flex;
}

.image-category{
float: left;
width: calc(100%/3);
flex-basis: 33.33%;
object-fit:cover;
background: red;
}

#product1{
max-width: calc(100%/3);
min-width: calc(100%/3);
max-height: 66%;
object-fit:cover;
}

#product2{
max-width: calc(100%/3);
min-width: calc(100%/3);
max-height: 66%;
object-fit:cover;
}

#product3{
max-width: calc(100%/3);
min-width: calc(100%/3);
max-height: 66%;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">



        <img class"image-category" id="product1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526512340740-9217d0159da9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmVydGljYWx8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
        <img class"image-category" id="product2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1459505/pexels-photo-1459505.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        <img class"image-category" id="product3" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/433989/pexels-photo-433989.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">

    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this because it is a typo. Both answers provide the reason why, along with some other tips.

Answer (score 0):

`id` has more `specificity` than classes. In your code, `class` is not applied because of less specificity value.

If you have only `class` and not `id` in your code, it will still work. But since your have used `float` property for the class selector. float behaves differently on HTML elements and takes them out of normal flow.

**UPDATE:** You actually have a typo in your code. That's why your class is not applied.

**HERE:** `class"image-category"`. you have forgot `=`. It should be `class="image-category"`

```css
.image-category {
  max-width: 33.33vw;
  min-width: 33.33vw;
  max-height: 66%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <img
        class="image-category"
        id="product1"
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526512340740-9217d0159da9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmVydGljYWx8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
      />
      <img
        class="image-category"
        id="product2"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1459505/pexels-photo-1459505.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
      />
      <img
        class="image-category"
        id="product3"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/433989/pexels-photo-433989.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Ya, I figured that.I was updating my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I wouldn't provide an answer, since this is partially a typo question:

1. You have a typo in your HTML, you're missing the `=` for your class, so the `image-category` CSS isn't being applied.
2. You don't need the `float` property at all. That's what `flex` is being used for.
3. You can use the shorthand for the `flex` property (flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis)
4. Set a max-width on your `.image-category` class.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.image-category {
  max-width: 33.333%;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image-category" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526512340740-9217d0159da9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmVydGljYWx8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
  <img class="image-category" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1459505/pexels-photo-1459505.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <img class="image-category" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/433989/pexels-photo-433989.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">

</div>
```